# How to submit sitemaps for large number of subdomains and which gets created for every user registration to google search console?

Tags: javascript, seo, subdomain, sitemap

I have a multi-tenant app. Every time a user registers, a site is created in the subdomain.
Lets say the site is https://example.com. When a user registers with the username foo, https://foo.example.com gets created.

Initially I thought I could have a sitemap at https://example.com/sitemap-users.xml which will contain all the sitemaps of all subdomains. But looks like this is not possible because subdomains are completely different website from domains.

I have close to 3k+ subdomains, so a better approach for me is to submit it programatically. How can I do that?

And if this is not possible, how do other websites achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't bother submitting sitemaps for each subdomain.  Sitemaps don't help SEO.  [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)